# AWS VPN to AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have a service provider offering an AWS VPN connection to their AWS VPC.  Their process is designed to work with an on premise connection.

However, I want to connect my AWS VPC to the AWS VPN they have created.

They have shared the VPN Connection Configuration file with me.
I have given them an Elastic IP I have set aside in my AWS account and it appears in the Connection Configuration file as the Tunnel (1&2) Interface Configuration, Outside IP Addresses, Customer Gateway.

What AWS assets on my side, do I need to setup to establish the connection?
Can anyone point me to a guide that describes the configuration steps needed?
Do I need to configure an AWS asset FIRST and THEN release the resulting public IP address for them to insert into the VPN Configuration file?

Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered VPC peering (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)? From your question the VPN appears to be unnecessary, unless the service provider refuses to play ball with VPC peering.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your Amazon VPC to remote networks and users using the following VPN connectivity options:

1. AWS Site-to-Site VPN
2. AWS Client VPN
3. AWS VPN CloudHub
4. Third party software VPN appliance

According to what You described, I think the first choice is the most suitable for You.
You can enable access to your remote network from your VPC by creating an AWS Site-to-Site VPN (Site-to-Site VPN) connection, and configuring routing to pass traffic through the connection.

Check out this pages for further details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html